# PHP: classes using each other

Tags: php

I have parent class Color and children, ColorRGBA and ColorHSLA. In class Color I want to use a static functions from these children, but I got error "Class 'Color' not found." Here is the same problem http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=469995 but `class Color;` doesn't seem to work in PHP.

Color.php:

```
include_once 'ColorRGBA.php';
include_once 'ColorHSLA.php';

class Color{
    public static function isValid(&$tokens, $i) {
        return ColorRGBA::isValid($tokens, $i) || ColorHSLA::isValid($tokens, $i);
    }
}
```

ColorHLSA.php and similarly ColorRGBA.php

```
include_once 'Color.php';

class ColorRGBA extends Color {
    public static function isValid(&$t, &$i) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How should I rebuild my class hierarchy or include directives? Or is there any other option how to make my code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this type of problem, perhaps you should think about implementing a [factory class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP).  If that isn't your style, another elegant way around this issue is it use [__autoload()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

As for the maintenance of the code. It is going to be difficult depending on how many colors you introduce.  Why not trying something like:

```
class Color{
    public static function isValid($type, &$tokens, $i){
        $class_name = 'Color'.$type;            
        if (!class_exists($class_name)) {
            throw new Exception('Missing '.$class_name.' class.');
        }

        $class_name::isValid(&$tokens, $i);
    }
}
```

*PHP 3.5+*

Comment: It is parser of CSS files, so there is valid only RGBA and HSLA colors unless they present CSS4 standard. You inspired me to create this solution `$r = 'ColorRGBA';  $h = 'ColorHSLA'; return $r::isValid($tokens, $i) || $h::isValid($tokens, $i);` It works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @user1440369: There are also named colors in CSS.

Comment: I have found only RGB values of named colors in CSS, so I've included this functionality to ColorRGBA class, or should I separate this functionality to another class?

Answer (score 2):

Yes in PHP there are no "forward declarations" like in C++. That's why `class Color;` is invalid in PHP.

Now why do you get `"Class 'Color' not found."`? The problem is that, this line

```
class ColorRGBA extends Color
```

gets executed before that line:

```
class Color {
```

So `Color` is indeed not defined. To solve this you could do the following:

```
class Color{
    public static function isValid(&$tokens, $i) {
        include_once 'ColorRGBA.php';
        include_once 'ColorHSLA.php';
        return ColorRGBA::isValid($tokens, $i) || ColorHSLA::isValid($tokens, $i);
    }
}
```

This works because the `Color` class is now fully defined and the `ColorRGBA`/`ColorHSLA` classes are defined only when `isValid` gets called.

You could also put `include_once` after the definition of the `Color` class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include ColorRGBA.php in Color.php and Color.php in ColorRGBA.php. You will get circular dependency. This is why you get class not found error.

Comment: When I remove `include_once "Color.php"` from ColorRGBA.php and ColorHSLA.php, the error is still there. And shouldn't include_once include resource only one time?

Comment: It's not about including it once. It's about including files in each other. It's called circular dependency. Try removing **include Color.php** statement from ColorRGBA.php and folowing **extends Color** statement. You can leave your Color class as is.